# Drupal update system not detecting latest (security) releases

Tags: drush, security

This morning I got e-mails about security updates and I know one of the modules, path_breadcrumb is installed on some of my sites. So I ssh into these sites, do drush pm-update --security-only and it says no updates available.

rm -rf ~/.drush/cache/download/*;rm -rf /tmp/drus*;drush cc drush;drush pm-update --security-only

still no security updates available. When I log into the frontend of these sites the available updates page also does not detect anything. It does list available updates that are as recent as 1 week ago. What can explain this delay?

Comment: When you go to the update page, are the modules that need an update grey?

Comment: No, they would just be yellow or green. Yellow ones even refer to recommended releases, but these will all be at least X days old and not reflect updates from 1 or 2 days ago.